# Replacement for "has_many ... counter_sql" in Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Rails 4.1 removed the `counter_sql` from `has_many` associations, so the following does no longer work:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :backers,
    -> { select('COMPLEX SQL QUERY') },
    through: :pledges,
    source: :backer,
    counter_sql: proc { "COMPLEX COUNT SQL QUERY" }

  (...)
end
```

I need a `counter_sql` here since with the COMPLEX SQL QUERY in `select`, AR does not build valid SQL when I do `project.backers.count`.

To fix this, I'd move this to a method like so:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :backers,
    -> { select('COMPLEX SQL QUERY') },
    through: :pledges,
    source: :backer

  def backers_count
    self.class.count_by_sql 'COMPLEX SQL QUERY'
  end

  (...)
end
```

Is this a good way to go or are there better approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an association extension

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :backers,
    -> { select('COMPLEX SQL QUERY') },
    through: :pledges,
    source: :backer do

    def count
      #query here
    end
  end
end
```

The association proxy is available as `proxy_association`, in particular `proxy_association.owner` returns the project object.

This overwrites the count method provided by default, so `some_project.backers.count` will call your custom query

Comment: A followup question though: The query inside the count method needs the `project.id` to work, how can I get this bit from within the count method?

Comment: A followup question is probably best asked as a question rather than in comments, but as I mentioned proxy_association.owner will return the project object