# Rails4 override has_many getter method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, overriding, has-many, eager-loading

I have a Rails 4.1.7 application, where we have `users` and `themes`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :themes
end

class Theme < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now, the user can create some own themes (then these themes will have their `user_id` set to the user's `id`), or can use any of the predefined themes (having `user_id` set to `null`)

What I would like to do is the following: to somehow change the `has_many` association so that when I call `@user.themes`, this bring me the predifined themes along with those of the user.

What I have tried:

1) to define an instance method instead of the `has_many` association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def themes
    Theme.where user_id: [id, nil]
  end
end
```

but since I would like to eager-load the themes with the user(s) (`includes(:themes)`), that won't really do.

2) to use some scope (`has_many :themes, -> { where user_id: nil }`), but it gives mySql queries like `... WHERE user_id = 123 AND user_id IS NULL`, which returns empty. I guess with Rails5 I could do it with something like `has_many :themes, -> { or.where user_id: nil }`, but changing the Rails version is not an option for now.

Comment: I think that it is a bad idea to rewrite association, because `Theme` without any user specified  in fact belongs to each user (many users), it is not a  `has_one - has_many` relation. I would recommend to using the other method to achieve your goal.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm using now. Only, it would be so much nicer to eager load it sometimes...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since posting my question, I tried many things to achieve my goal. One was interesting and, I guess, worth to be mentioned:

I tried to unscope the `has_many` assiciation using [unscope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/active_record_querying.html#unscope) or [rewhere](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/active_record_querying.html#rewhere), and it looked like this:

```
has_many :themes, -> user = self { # EDIT: `= self` can even be omitted
  u_id = user.respond_to?(:id) ? user.id : user.ids

  unscope(where: :user_id).where(user_id: [u_id, nil])
  # or the same but with other syntax:
  rewhere(user_id: [u_id, nil])
}
```

When I tried `@user.themes`, it worked like wonder, and gave the following mySql line:

```
SELECT `themes`.* FROM `themes`
       WHERE ((`themes`.`user_id` = 123 OR `themes`.`user_id` IS NULL))
```

But when I tried to eager load it (why I started my research after all), it simply refused to unscope the query, and gave the same old `user_id = 123 AND user_id = NULL` line.

After all, @Ilya's comment convinced me along with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009768/porting-complicated-has-many-relationships-to-rails-4-1-without-finder-sql#34444220) answer, that it is one thing to use the `has_many` for querying, but it has other sides, like assigning for example, and overriding it for one's sake can spoil many other things.

So I decided to remain with my nice method, only I gave it a more specific name to avoid future confusion:

```
def available_themes
  Theme.where user_id: [id, nil]
end
```

As for @AndreyDeineko's response - since he continually refuses to answer my question, always answering something that has never been asked -, I still fail to understand why his method (having the same reults as my `available_themes`, but using 3 additional queries) would be a better solution.